# How can I make a website so that an image lines up with cards that are stack on one another?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Not sure if I explained it well, but I want to make a website so that the image at the right of the page lines up with two cards at the left of the page. Here is an example of what I want:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBvTQ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBvTQ.jpg)

Here is my code right now:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>#</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="p-3" id="topHeader">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="row">
          <div class="col-xs 12">
            <h1>This is a Website </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">about</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="card mb-5 shadow-sm">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg/1200px-Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg" class="img-fluid" />

        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h3>title</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-text">
            <p>
              a little text
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-5 shadow-sm">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg/1200px-Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg" class="img-fluid" />

        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="card-title">
            <h3>title</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-text">
            <p>
              a little text
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">button</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="image">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg/1200px-Altja_j%C3%B5gi_Lahemaal.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-zYPOMqeu1DAVkHiLqWBUTcbYfZ8osu1Nd6Z89ify25QV9guujx43ITvfi12/QExE"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <footer>
      copyright me and this website
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

I only want the image to line up with the cards in screens like laptops/PCs.

I've been trying to change the max-width/height in CSS, but nothing changes. I don't know if I'm incorrectly using the id in CSS, because I'm not very familiar with using Bootstrap with CSS.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest a 2x2 grid, with a card in each grid square in the left column, and the image stretched across both grid squares in the right column.

```css
.s1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  gap: 1em;
}

.s1 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.s1 .card {
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.s1 .right-col {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.s1 .right-col img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="s1">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150">
    <p>Card One</p>
    <p><button>Button One</button></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/152">
    <p>Card Two</p>
    <p><button>Button Two</button></p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col"><img src="https://picsum.photos/800"></div>
</section>
```